# When I return the call super.method(), my debugger shows a value and the method returns null

Tags: java, string, null, return

When I call the below method, it returns null.

```
public String determineAction(String someAction){
    if(someAction.length() > 4){
        return someAction;
    }else{
        return super.determineAction(someAction)
    }
 }
```

When I break out the return statement into a String return value

```
 String action = super.determineAction(someAction);
 return action;
```

the value is returned.

Care to share some of the mechanics? I do not remember seeing this behavior with other objects or primitive data types.

Below is the super method

```
protected String determineAction(String someAction) {
        if(someAction!= null) {
            switch(someAction) {
                case ACCEPT: return ACTION_ACCEPT;
                case CANCEL: return ACTION_CANCEL;
                case UPDATE: return ACTION_UPDATE;
                case PASS: return ACTION_PASS;
                default: return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the source of the method you are overriding?

Comment: Can you post the code of the parentesco method?

Comment: Please post the super class which you are extending

Comment: `someAction.length` isn't valid Java if it's a String.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't typing in an editor. I just applied the correct syntax.

Comment: Also, as I noted above, I don't think this is indicative of an issue in super - as I saw a return value in my debugger

Comment: Show declarations of `ACCEPT` and `ACTION_ACCEPT` etc, and show the exact value of `someAction`. Even better, create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) (if you go through the exercise of creating a SSCCE, your error will most likely become obvious).

Comment: By the way, you need a **semicolon** after `return` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following code snippets.

Parent class

```
public class Father {
    protected String determineAction(String someAction) {
        if(someAction!= null) {
            switch(someAction) {
                case "abc": return someAction+someAction+someAction;
                case "ab": return someAction+someAction;
                default: return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Child class

```
public class Son extends Father {

    public String determineAction(String someAction){
        if(someAction.length() > 4)
            return someAction;
        return super.determineAction(someAction);
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Son mySon = new Son();
        System.out.println(mySon.determineAction("abc"));   // prints abcabcabc // father determineAction()
        System.out.println(mySon.determineAction("a1234")); // prints a1234 // son determineAction()
    }
}
```